# Browser cookies being (selectively) reset unexpectedly

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies

I think some browser cookies are being unexpectedly reset. How do I prevent this or figure out what is happening?

I changed some settings on a few web apps. The changed settings stick for a while, but after some time they reset to the defaults (I am assuming these settings are stored in browser cookies):

- https://hckrnews.com/. "Link to HackerWeb" reverts to unselected.
- https://app.simplenote.com/. "Line length" reverts to "Narrow."

This started happening recently (within the past few weeks/months.) I think this is an issue with the browser and not the web apps because multiple were sites were affected starting around the same time. I was using both sites fine for years without this issue.

I am not sure if this is Chrome-only, but I have only seen it on Chrome. **update:** it does not seem to happen in Firefox. I set these settings in Firefox when I posted this question, and they are still set while Chrome has reset, again.

Comment: This just may be a problem with the Websites. Other than that you should try using other browsers or reinstalling chrome. Also if you have a CleanUp Utility tool installed or an AntiVirus, these programs may mess up with the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies come with an expiry date, so a policy change could have given them a shorter time to live. This should be easy to verify since you are using Chrome. Click on the icon near the bookmark star, then show cooking and other site data and expand each cookie to see when they are scheduled to expire.

The other possibility is that you have installed privacy software or extension that are design to remove traces of visited sites. Many different software have these features particularly to combat invasive tracking practices. It could even be a new feature of an anti-virus / anti-malware recently installed as update.